# Delete last character from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I delete the last character from an input in JQuery?  For example, `onclick` of something, it deletes the last character (a comma in my case) from an input field.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$(input).val(
    function(index, value){
        return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
})
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to chop of any last character (not just comma, space), you can use `slice`:

```
var $myInput = $('#myInput');
$myInput.val($myInput.val().slice(0, -1));
```

You can combine it with `$.trim()` to remove extra spaces:

```
$myInput.val($.trim($myInput.val()).slice(0, -1));
```

Answer (score 6):

The following works, albeit it's perhaps a little clunky:

```
$('#idOfButtonToClick').click(
    function(){
        var inputString = $('#idOfInput').val();
        var shortenedString = inputString.substr(0,(inputString.length -1));
        $('#idOfInput').val(shortenedString);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ew9kL/2/).

Revised demo, that checks for the last character being a `,` character before truncating the string:

```
$('#idOfButtonToClick').click(
    function(){
        var inputString = $('#idOfInput').val();
        if (inputString.charAt(inputString.length - 1) == ',') {
            var shortenedString = inputString.substr(0,(inputString.length -1));
        $('#idOfInput').val(shortenedString);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ew9kL/1/).

Comment: +1 for answering what's asked, but, you could easily optimize this by using a single `$("#idOfInput")`, and using a function in `val()`. Forked: http://jsfiddle.net/gWMDT/1/

Answer (score 4):

These two lines will remove a trailing comma from a particular input. I'll leave it up to you to decide when it needs to be run (on change/on button click, etc).

```
var $theInput = $('#myInput');
$theInput.val($theInput.val().replace(/,$/, ''));
```

If you also want to get rid of any possible whitespace at the end, change the regex to this:

```
/\s*,\s*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.backspace', function(){
    let value = $('#output').val();
    console.log(value);
    v = value.slice(0,-1);
    let v = value.slice(0,-1);
    console.log(v);
    $('#output').value(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function back_space() {

       var arrayexit = document.getElementById("tbtwo").value;

       for (var i = 0; i < arrayexit.length; i++) 
        {
            var output = arrayexit.slice(0, -1);
            document.getElementById("tbtwo").value = output;

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html code**

```
<input oninput="remove(this.value)" type="text" id="mytext" />
```

**Js code**

```
function remove(val) {
    document.querySelector("#mytext").value = val.slice(0, -1);
}
```